# Change date format to "dd-mm-yyyy" in Django rest framwork

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hi below is my request payload and i am using normal serializer and i want to save date in "dd-mm-YYYY" format in DB

```
{
    "start_date": "2022-10-10",
    "end_date": "2022-12-10"
}
```

Here is my serializer

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    start_date = serializers.DateField()
    end_date = serializers.DateField()
```

Note: I don't want to change the requested payload date format only change on saving the record by changing the format to "dd-mm-YYY".

Here is my django settings.py file configuration

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'common.exception.custom_exception_handler.custom_exception_handler',
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
    'NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY': "detail",
    'DATE_FORMAT': ["%d-%M-%Y"]
}
```

Comment: Are you facing any issues? Elaborate on the issue that you're facing and what you're expecting.

Comment: @JPG I am not able to save the date in "dd-mm-YYY" format into the DB, and in request payload the date is in "YYY-mm-dd" format so I have to convert it in "dd-mm-YYYY" format and save it into the DB.

Comment: I think Django stores the date as a datetime.date object, which is a naive format-unaware date. At the DB level it is most likely stored as a timestamp. None of these representations have any format attributes. You can format the date as you wish after retrieving the date object from database or look at the settings options that changes the date format (DATE_FORMAT, DATETIME_FORMAT and TIME_FORMAT)

Comment: Yes but by setting DATE_FORMAT settings to "dd-mm-YYY" then it should expect the date "12-10-2022" in this format from the request payload but in my case the request payload would be in "2022-12-10" @IgorMoraru

Comment: There is also an option for input format: DATE_INPUT_FORMAT

Comment: I have tried this one too but expecting same from the request payload @IgorMoraru

Comment: You should add these options to REST_FRAMEWORK object in settings

Comment: In short from frontend in any format the date would come we have to save in "%d-%m-%YYYY" format into the DB.

Comment: Yes i have used in REST_FRAMEWORK options only @IgorMoraru